# How do you track down dependencies for ASP.NET Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, dependencies, vs-web-site-project

The dynamic compile-on-the fly approach seems to fall outside the capacity for the typical tools which would extract this kind of information.  I know I may be better off converting to a Web Application, BUT I would like to ask how it could be done in the case of a Web Site Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspnet_compiler can still leave you with a boatload of assemblies to scan. You can chase it with aspnet_merge, or use a [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) to run the compiler and merge utility for you. WDP can give you a single assembly for the entire web site.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [aspnet_compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(VS.80).aspx) and then scan for dependencies on the compiled assemblies.